# Convert Oracle PL/SQL procedure declaration to T-SQL procedure

Tags: sql-server, oracle, stored-procedures

Can somebody help me convert the oracle procedure declaration to SQL procedure declaration?
I am having difficulties in converting **arr_list**
and the **cursor groupCurType**. Please help!
Below is my SQL server create procedure and declaration part:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY standard_extract IS
    PROCEDURE process_std_extract (p_debug IN NUMBER DEFAULT 0
    , p_schema IN STRING DEFAULT 'SCHEMA'
    , p_result_level IN STRING DEFAULT 'FULL') AS
      v_reviewset VARCHAR2(255);
      type arr_list is table of number index by varchar2(5);
      v_groupArr arr_list;
      type groupCurType IS REF CURSOR;
      v_groupCur groupCurType;
      v_group number;
      v_grouptype varchar2(5);
      v_numcol varchar2(100);
      type gtype_list is table of varchar2(50) index by varchar2(5);
      v_gtypeArr gtype_list;
      key varchar2(5);
      v_start number;
      v_end number;
      v_msrStart date;

      END process_std_extract;
```

Comment: can you provide the original Oracle procedure , the new SQL Server one and the error you got when you try to compile on SQL Server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can somebody help me convert the oracle procedure declaration to SQL procedure declaration?

Yes.  The signature does not include any of the local variable declarations.  And those would likely be significantly different in a TSQL implementation.

The procedure declaration would simply be:

```
create or alter procedure process_std_extract @debug int = 0, 
                                               @schema varchar(20) = 'SCHEMA',
                                               @result_level varchar(20) = 'FULL'
as
begin
   . . .
end
```

If you want help translating the procedure body you can try [SQL Server Migration Assistant for Oracle.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/oracle/sql-server-migration-assistant-for-oracle-oracletosql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: The OP did not say signature, they said declaration (i.e. the local variables) and particularly mentioned `arr_list` (associative array) and `groupCurType` (cursor) types.

Comment: Right.  But that's all implementation detail that would normally not be directly translated to TSQL.